# Webscrape VBA - List

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to set up a webscraping VBA code to import data into Excel from this website: https://www.thewindpower.net/windfarms_list_en.php

I wish to launch this webpage, select a country and then scrape the data from the table below (including url from the name column).

Yet, I am stuck with several points:

- How can I select the country I wish in VBA code ?
- How can I select the table as there is no id or class in the tag ?
- How can I import the URL included in the name column ?

Here is the code I have already prepared (based on some research on the web:

```
Sub Grabdata()

'dimension (set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer

'start a new browser instance
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
'make browser visible
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate to page with needed data
objIE.navigate "https://www.thewindpower.net/windfarms_list_en.php"
'wait for page to load
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'we will output data to excel, starting on row 1
y = 1

'look at all the 'tr' elements in the 'table' with id 'myTable',
'and evaluate each, one at a time, using 'ele' variable
For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr")
    'show the text content of 'tr' element being looked at
    Debug.Print ele.textContent
    'each 'tr' (table row) element contains 4 children ('td') elements
    'put text of 1st 'td' in col A
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
    'put text of 2nd 'td' in col B
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent
    'put text of 3rd 'td' in col C
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = ele.Children(2).textContent
    'put text of 4th 'td' in col D
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).Value = ele.Children(3).textContent
    'increment row counter by 1
    y = y + 1
'repeat until last ele has been evaluated
Next

'save the Excel workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

End Sub

Comment: What would you do selecting the table? Are you willing to fetch content from that table? You don't need IE for that. You simply can send a post http requests along with appropriate parameters to populate the table.

Comment: I would like to fetch the all table depending on the country I would have selected (like UK for exemple).

And after having obtained this table (with URL included in name column) I wish to run another macro for each row of the table by visiting each URL on the name and get some data from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most scrapeable pages will almost always have a static page layout so it's fairly safe to select elements using their index.

The code below selects the container element with id `bloc_texte` and then selects the second table inside.

If you're planning on doing a lot of requests as your comment suggests, you should add some code to slow down your requests (`Application.wait` type deal). Firing off request after request is likely to annoy the host.

```
' Required References
' Microsoft HTML Object Library
' Microsoft XML, v6.0

Sub Main()
    GetData ("GB")
End Sub

Sub GetData(ByVal Location As String)

Dim Request As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60: Set Request = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

Dim Result As HTMLDocument: Set Result = New HTMLDocument

Request.Open "POST", "https://www.thewindpower.net/windfarms_list_en.php", False
Request.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Request.send "action=submit&pays=" & Location

Result.body.innerHTML = Request.responseText

Dim oRows As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim oRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim oCells As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim oCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim oLinks As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set oRows = Result.getElementById("bloc_texte").getElementsByTagName("table")(2).getElementsByTagName("tr")

Dim iRow As Integer 'output row counter
Dim iColumn As Integer 'output column counter
Dim Sheet As Worksheet 'output sheet

Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
iRow = 1
iColumn = 1

For Each oRow In oRows
    If Not oRow.className = "puce_texte" Then
        Set oCells = oRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
        For Each oCell In oCells
            Set oLinks = oCell.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If oLinks.Length = 0 Then
                Sheet.Cells(iRow, iColumn).Value = oCell.innerText
            Else
                Sheet.Cells(iRow, iColumn).Value = Replace(oLinks(0).getAttribute("href"), "about:", "")
            End If
            iColumn = iColumn + 1
        Next oCell
        iRow = iRow + 1
        iColumn = 1
    End If
Next oRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Nick ! 
I still get a problem with the line below
" Dim Request As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60: Set Request = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60"

I get an error message " user-type not defined", do you have any idea why ?

Comment: You need to add the references. In the VBA Editor -> Tools -> References and select the two items shown at the top of the code block.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly !
I am starting working on the second part of my scrapping (the page by page part) !

Comment: Do you have any resources with which I could learn index selection as you are using it ? 
I am already getting stuck in the second part of my process and I think it would help me a lot !

Comment: I just use the Chrome Dev Tools. Find the closest container element with an id, count how many whatever elements appear before the one you need. You could also select the target element (the table) and open the context menu (Copy->Copy XPath) which will usually give you all the info you need to target your data. eg `//*[@id="bloc_texte"]/table[2]` -> element with id bloc_texte, child table number 2

Comment: Ok very clear, thanks !
And how would you update the request to just load the page based on a url povided ? (without any POST method for the dropdown list)
After that how would you check whether there are some "Part" or not ?

Comment: Change it from post to get, remove setrequestheader line and remove the parameters from the send command. There are lots of examples of using xmlhttp in VBA for Post and Get requests here on SO, just have a search.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!
Indeed there are many example, I have used / tried some of them yet I need to implement a if statement due to the structure of the website and I find it a bit tricky to be honnest. If you have some time to have a look to my other post it would be so much helpful !

Comment: In my other program, the error is apparently in the request to load the page, do you have any idea how I could fix it ?