# Webscrape VBA with if condition

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to import the bullet point from a website into an excel table (each bulletpoint filling with a li tag).

Yet I am facing an important difficulty as some page I would like to scrape have several  "Part" (Part #1, Part #2, like this one https://www.thewindpower.net/windfarm_en_793_virtsu-i.php) and other haven't (like this one https://www.thewindpower.net/windfarm_en_7410_khizi.php)

I having already come up with a draft of a code that I believe could start, yet, I still have some issue and I get an error message ("Time out").
Do you have any idea how I could fix it ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

```
Sub Page()
GetPage ("https://www.thewindpower.net/windfarm_en_1922_a-capelada-i.php")
End Sub



Sub GetPage(URL As String)

Dim count As Integer

Dim Request As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60: Set Request = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

Dim Result As HTMLDocument: Set Result = New HTMLDocument

Request.Open "GET", URL, False
Request.send

Result.body.innerHTML = Request.responseText

Dim oRows As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim oRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim oCells As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim oCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim oLinks As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

'Set Generalities
Set oRows = Result.getElementsByTagName("ul")(4).getElementsByTagName("li")

Dim iRow As Integer 'output li counter
Dim iColumn As Integer 'output column counter
Dim Sheet As Worksheet 'output sheet

iRow = 1
iColumn = 1

Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")


count = Result.getElementsByTagName("h3").Length


If count > 0 Then
    '# f Part on the page, 2 for the moment
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim o As Integer
    p = count / 2
    
    'Counter for each Part identified
    For o = 1 To p
                'Set Generalities data

                iRow = 1
                iColumn = 1
                            
                For Each oRow In oRows
                    Set oCells = oRow.getElementsByTagName("li")
                        For Each oCell In oCells
                                Sheet.Cells(iRow, iColumn).Value = oCell.innerText
                                iColumn = iColumn + 1
                        Next oCell
                        iRow = iRow + 1
                Next oRow
                        
                'Set Detail data
                Set oRows2 = Result.getElementsByTagName("h3")(o).getElementsByTagName("li")
                
                For Each oRow In oRows2
                    Set oCells = oRow.getElementsByTagName("li")
                        For Each oCell In oCells
                                Sheet.Cells(iRow, iColumn).Value = oCell.innerText
                                iColumn = iColumn + 1
                        Next oCell
                        iRow = iRow + 1
                        iColumn = 1
                Next oRow
                                   
        iRow = iRow + 1
        'insert a row
        Range("iRow").Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
        
        'increment Part counter
    Next o
    
    Else
    
        'Set Generalities data
            For Each oRow In oRows
                    Set oCells = oRow.getElementsByTagName("li")
                        For Each oCell In oCells
                                Sheet.Cells(iRow, iColumn).Value = oCell.innerText
                                iColumn = iColumn + 1
                        Next oCell
                        iRow = iRow + 1
                Next oRow
                        
                        
            'Set Detail data
            Set oRows2 = Result.getElementsByTagName("ul")(5).getElementsByTagName("li")
                
                For Each oRow In oRows2
                    Set oCells = oRow.getElementsByTagName("li")
                        For Each oCell In oCells
                                Sheet.Cells(iRow, iColumn).Value = oCell.innerText
                                iColumn = iColumn + 1
                        Next oCell
                        iRow = iRow + 1
                        iColumn = 1
                Next oRow
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Would help to indicate the desired output format (other than just 1 part per row. For example, does a row include the production forecast? Do you need the headers Details and Localisation? Is Generalities to be included even though not a part?  Should part 1 from both Details and Localisation all go on to one row and the same for the parts 2 and 3?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback QHarr ! 
I fact for each page I would like to get a row in excel with (i) the bulletpoint from the Generalities section and (ii) those in the Details part; each bulletpoint in a different column
If there is only one part I would like to get one row with these above bulletpoint
If there is several part I would like to get one row for each part with the Generalities (the same for every part) as well as the Details without the Production forecast
I already have a table based on the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759517/webscrap-vba-list

Comment: Would generalities have its own row as it doesn't appear to be linked with a particular detail part?

Comment: Indeed in fact info in Generalities are about all the Part, thus I would like to have in the row about Part 1, but also in the row about part 2, Part 3, ...

Comment: @QHarr I have updated the code above based on my research and attempt, it is not working yet but at least there is an idea of the structure that could be used, could you tell me what you think about it ?

Comment: I am now getting much closer I think, yet I still face some error message ("Operation time out"), do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I was at work.

Comment: No worries QHarr, you are already helping me a lot I can wait ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

I would gather a nodeList via css selectors to match on the relevant nodes. I would have two separate nodeLists. One for the generalities and another for the parts. I would determine the number of parts (as they repeat) and loop to those number of parts; concatenating the html for the repeated part that comes later with the former. Then put that combined html into a surrogate HTMLDocument variable and make a new nodeList of all the `li` elements contained. Use a helper function to return the text of the nodeList nodes in an array and then write that out to the sheet on a new combined text per row basis.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WindInfo()
    'VBE> Tools > References:
    '1. Microsoft, XML v6
    '2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
    '3. Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.thewindpower.net/windfarm_en_7410_khizi.php", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim generalities As Object, arrGen(), partsList As Object
    
    Dim r As Long

    Set generalities = html.querySelectorAll("#bloc_texte table ~ table li")
    arrGen = GetNodesTextAsArray(generalities)
    
    Dim parts As Object, numberOfParts As Long
    
    Set partsList = html.querySelectorAll("h1 ~ h3, ul ~ h3")
    
    r = 1
    
    If partsList.Length > 0 Then
    
        numberOfParts = html.querySelectorAll("h1 ~ h3, ul ~ h3").Length / 2
    
        Set parts = html.querySelectorAll("h3 + ul")
       
        Dim i As Long, liNodes As Object, arr()
        Dim html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set html2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        
        For i = 0 To numberOfParts - 1
            ws.Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arrGen)) = arrGen
            html2.body.innerHTML = parts.Item(i).outerHTML & parts.Item(i + numberOfParts).outerHTML
            Set liNodes = html2.querySelectorAll("li")
            arr = GetNodesTextAsArray(liNodes)
            ws.Cells(r, 5).Resize(1, UBound(arr)) = arr
            r = r + 1
        Next
    Else
        Dim alternateNodeList As Object: Set alternateNodeList = html.querySelectorAll("#bloc_texte h1 + ul")
        
        If alternateNodeList.Length >= 1 Then
            arr = GetNodesTextAsArray(alternateNodeList.Item(1).getElementsByTagName("li"))
        Else
            arr = Array("No", "Data", vbNullString)
        End If
        ws.Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arrGen)) = arrGen
        ws.Cells(r, 5).Resize(1, UBound(arr)) = arr
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetNodesTextAsArray(ByVal nodeList As Object) As Variant()
    Dim i As Long, results()
    
    If nodeList.Length = 0 Then
        GetNodesTextAsArray = Array("No", "Data", vbNullString)
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ReDim results(1 To nodeList.Length)

    For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
        results(i + 1) = nodeList.Item(i).innerText
    Next i
    GetNodesTextAsArray = results
End Function
```

---

**References:**

1. [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer QHarr ! It looks to work great !
Yet with pages with no Part (becasue there is only one), like on this one https://www.thewindpower.net/windfarm_en_7410_khizi.php it only detects the generalities, do you think that I could fix it with an if statement based on the value of numberOfParts ?

Comment: I would set html.querySelectorAll("h1 ~ h3, ul ~ h3").Length into a variable and test if the length is = 0; then if >0 you can divide that variable/2 to get numberOfParts etc.... otherwise you will need to handle a /0 error.

Comment: I have just tried it and apparently it doesn't change anything, the Details part is not detected, should I change the for loop at the end of the first sub ?

Comment: Sorry.. you wanted parts and generalities didn't you? Details wasn't mentioned in question.

Comment: You can test html for presence of Part # as a string and if not present assume generalities and desc are present and can be matched instead with _#bloc_texte h1 + ul_ as the css selector. You then only want first two nodes and not the third i.e. index 0 and index 1.

Comment: Your answer is already very helpful ! Yes exactly, I wouls like to get in a row generalities and part 1 detail, then in another row generalities and part 2 detail and so on, and for that your code works perfectly. Yet, if I change the URL by another one with only one part (and thus it is not written as a part, like here: https://www.thewindpower.net/windfarm_en_7410_khizi.php), the code extract only generalities.

Comment: Try to put that sort of info into the question in advance in future. I suggest you have a look and see if there are any different cases that come up with different urls as well and let me know before I update the above. See whether the assumptions I stated in comment above will suffice i.e. if Part #, as a string, is not present on the page, can the items you want be matched with _#bloc_texte h1 + ul_

Comment: You can test the matches in the browser by pressing F12 to open dev tools and going to _elements_ tab, then press Ctrl + F to open find box and type _#bloc_texte h1 + ul_ then hit enter. It will return the number of matches on the page. As you hit enter repeatedly it will cycle through matches and highlight was is matched on the actual webpage. Check if matches the items you want for cases where parts # are missing.

Comment: Yes I will, I am realising that it was not clear enough, sorry for that. I have checked several url (c.15) of the website and those with "no" part seem to have all the same structure: the details are included in the 2nd _#bloc_texte h1 + ul_

Comment: In fact I am realizing that even for the url with several part it is not exactly that since I would need to have the generalities at the beginning of each of the row of each part.
For the url example we used, I would need to get "Name", "Country" and "County" at the begining of each row (in fact in 3 columns before "City"), do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Having my dinner at mo

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot QHarr ! Now I just need to find a way to execute this code on a list of url !

Comment: Have a go and you can always ask a follow-up question. You need a loop over urls with the .Get url inside the loop; r increments each time so that should be a problem so long as that code is inside the loop.

Comment: I have tried several things, it was working pretty well for 20 or 30 entry, yet when I tried with 200 some errors started to appear, in particular concerning the GetNodesTextAsArray.
I'm gonna ask a follow up below

Comment: If you have the time to have a look, you can find the follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62784441/webscrap-vba-inside-a-for-loop-follow-up

Comment: I've updated my answer above. It is a bit of a messy patch for now to deal with 0 nodeList.Length

Comment: Thank you ! Let me know if you have ideas to fix that differently.