# Webscrape inside a for loop - Follow up

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Following my previous question [Webscrape VBA with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765340/webscrap-vba-with-if-condition/62779743?noredirect=1#comment111027128_62779743), I started trying to automate the procedure for a list of url from this website [here](https://www.thewindpower.net/windfarms_list_en.php) that I prepared in my excel document. When I tried for 20 and 30 url it worked perfectly, yet when I increased it, a "Script out of range error" occurred concerning the ReDim in the GetNodesTextAsArray, do you have any idea why ?
After some research I Tried to replace it by a for loop but it doesn't chagne anything.

```
Public Sub WindInfo()
'VBE> Tools > References:
'1. Microsoft, XML v6
'2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
'3. Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim url As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim r As Long


r = 1

For j = 1 To 20

url = Worksheets("List").Cells(j, 1).Value

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim generalities As Object, arrGen(), partsList As Object
    
    

    Set generalities = html.querySelectorAll("#bloc_texte table ~ table li")
    arrGen = GetNodesTextAsArray(generalities)
    
    Dim parts As Object, numberOfParts As Long
    
    Set partsList = html.querySelectorAll("h1 ~ h3, ul ~ h3")
    
    
    If partsList.Length > 0 Then
    
        numberOfParts = html.querySelectorAll("h1 ~ h3, ul ~ h3").Length / 2
    
        Set parts = html.querySelectorAll("h3 + ul")
       
        Dim i As Long, liNodes As Object, arr()
        Dim html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set html2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        
        For i = 0 To numberOfParts - 1
            ws.Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arrGen)) = arrGen
            html2.body.innerHTML = parts.Item(i).outerHTML & parts.Item(i + numberOfParts).outerHTML
            Set liNodes = html2.querySelectorAll("li")
            arr = GetNodesTextAsArray(liNodes)
            ws.Cells(r, 5).Resize(1, UBound(arr)) = arr
            r = r + 1
        Next
        
    Else
        arr = GetNodesTextAsArray(html.querySelectorAll("#bloc_texte h1 + ul").Item(1).getElementsByTagName("li"))
        ws.Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arrGen)) = arrGen
        ws.Cells(r, 5).Resize(1, UBound(arr)) = arr
        r = r + 1
    End If
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Next

End Sub


Public Function GetNodesTextAsArray(ByVal nodeList As Object) As Variant()
Dim i As Long, results()

ReDim results(1 To nodeList.Length)

   

For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    results(i + 1) = nodeList.Item(i).innerText
Next i
GetNodesTextAsArray = results
End Function
```

Comment: What happens in your function when `nodeList.Length` is zero?

Comment: In fact it is not supposed to be zero in any situation (based on what I have observed on url. You think that it could generate this kind of error ? What would you do if nodeList.Length is zero ?

Comment: Well you have the code so you can check to see if the length is zero when it errors.  As for what to do in that case that's really your call.

Comment: Indeed you are right it is set to 0 at a moment (for this url: https://www.thewindpower.net/windfarm_en_22806_aulnay-l’aitre.php), yet I don't know why neither how I am supposed to cope with it; could you give me some ideas ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here?  If there are no matches on the page then maybe that means either the URL is wrong, or there are no matches to be had.  I can't tell from here (that URL you posted goes to a 404)

Answer (score 0):

9/10 the problem with VBA webscraping is page loading related.

So what you want to do is try an error handler that Loops while the page loads, and then tests to see if the element appears on the page.

I'll leave the code to you, but the timing here is essentially everything since even status code checking and waiting for the document to be loaded checking, is not a guarantee everything you need is loaded.

Even with great tools like selenium and puppeteer you still need to check / handle element loading and timing, and cant just assume, since document loaded, the element is there.

makes sense?

Comment: Finally QHarr tackled this point on my previous question. QHarr introduces some elements to deal with nodeList.Length = 0, has Tim Williams suggested above.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765340/webscrap-vba-with-if-condition